# carrierwave и jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте!

Новичок в rails( и совсем слабые знания js), поэтому простите за такой вопрос.
Есть модель House необходимо создать форму со свойствами и фотографиями. Сначала использовал гем carrierwave получается достаточно грубо, допустим если надо добавить несколько фотографий нужно использовать ctrl(нет возможности добавить в форму по одной фотографии или удалить лишнюю).

Почитал про jQuery-File-Upload. Судя по данному примеру https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6 придется создать модель Picture и видимо связать модели с помощью has_many belongs_to. Но какую тогда делать форму или нужно делать две формы отдельно для каждой модели и передавать для Pictures id_house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сначала использовал гем carrierwave получается достаточно грубо

Грубо совсем не из-за `carrierwave`-а, а из-за того, что сразу в `input` нельзя несколько файлов прицепить. Просто нужно много input-ов и на стороне сервера их обрабывать `carrierwave`-ом, можно даже отложенно. И да в примере вам написали, что нужна модель `Picture`, и в ней соотвественно поля `carrierwave`-а. Но это было очевидно и без использования `carrierwave`. т.е. если у вас есть дом, то он имеет много фоток (по-русски, у него есть много фоток). Вот вам и описание связи вышло, получим:

```
class House
   has_many :pictures
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end

class Picture
   belongs_to :house
   #... всё что нужно для carrierwave
end
```

1. Первый вариант, самое простое, что приходит в голову это использовать вложенные записи:

   ```
   class House
      has_many :pictures
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
   end
   ```

   Задаются вложенные записи с помощью метода класса [`::accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), который позволяет использовать вложенные записи при сохранении, в вашем случае это нужно, чтобы вложенные фото прикрепились к дому. Обратите внимание на то, что с помощью сего свойства также можно и удалять вложенные записи, а не только добавлять.

   Хотя в том [описании](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6) даже пример кода есть для загрузки, однако, поскольку он не вполне такой какой требуется, можно сделать как-то так: формы вы одну делаете, для дома, просто кроме полей для дома вы включаете в неё поля атрибутов картинок, и они таким неслабым массивом все идут при обновлении на сервер:

   ```
   <%= form_for @house, url: houses_path }  do |f| %>
      # ...
      <% f.fields_for @house.pictures do |pic| %>
         <%= pic.file_field :avatar %>
         #... тут уже код идёт из примера с jQuery-File-Upload
      <%- end %>
   <%- end %>
   ```

   Также не забудьте в контроллере правильно обрабатывать вложенные записи на сильных параметрах.
2. Можно сделать как вы предлагаете, то есть форму для дома и много форм для фоток, на каждую по форме. Только тут ограничение такое, что формы фоток могут появиться только в том случае, если запись дома уже создана, и да в форме фотки должно присутствовать задающее дом поле, к которому относится фотка. Тогда тут можно обойтись без вложенных записей.

Comment: Спасибо, используя первый метод наткнулся на проблему с update то есть в место обновления записи в таблице фотографий происходит добавление новой записи( то есть теперь у одного дома две фотографии, вместо одной замененной.. ну и т.д. 3, 4...) 

почитал вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944065/nested-attribute-update-attributes-uses-insert-rather-than-update про такое решение config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise , но в консоли выходит ошибка что не хватает id..

Comment: @nikfor какого ид не хватает? там в первом варианте проблема скоре та, что обновляться будут (по замыслу) все фото, заже те которые были сохранены до того, а это не круто, надо бы поиграться в консоли, посмотреть какие параметры просто не меняют свойств картинки, напр, толко ели передать ему реальный id картинки, а не её саму

Comment: @nikfor там в решении по ссылке пишут. что нужен ид для обновления а не создания новых объектов, полностью согласен, более того,  не затронутый объект не нужно посылать на сервер, а только его ид

Comment: спасибо вам большое за отзывчивость! Да вы правы, я сам немного затупил. то есть я примерно вот так писал house.photos.update(image: pictures_attributes(:image)) и не передавал id фотографии. sql не зная id создавал новую запись... теперь я сначала удаляю все фотографии потом заново создаю, есть предполагается что все фотографии заранее загружены в поля формы и с сервера и новые с компьютера пользователя.

Comment: @nikfor не за что, только пожалуй каждый раз пересоздавать записи для фоток это как-то накладно выходит.

Comment: как то не придумал другой способ, ведь юзер скажем может удалить все фотографии и загрузить новые?

Comment: @nikfor ну да, так удалять то тоже можно с поммощью `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: точно! спасибо еще раз!  :-| печально от того что я сам не додумался